# How can I render the fields and datatable by using <p:panelGrid>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have no idea how to render the below image with input fields and datatable with the exact alignment in UI.

I referred some documentation with examples, but I can't find the pattern for datatable. Attached the image below. Kindly share your thoughts for this as outline.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using PrimeFlex instead of `p:panelGrid`.

You basically need a 3 column grid layout. See the first example:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/gridsystem

An the input can be done using form layout. See the horizontal examples:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/formlayout

For the data table, simply use the `p:dataTable`. See: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml